# How to start datepicker dialog(daterangepicker) from fragment?

Tags: java, android-fragments, daterangepicker, datepickerdialog

I am using a library to select date range, from here 
[link to that class](https://github.com/yesidlazaro/DateRangePicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/lazaroyesid/daterangepicker/MainActivity.java)

I don't know how to use DateRangePicker from fragment and how to use it, to store data.

Here is my code.

Fragment class:

```
public class LaborerProfile extends Fragment implements DateRangePickerFragment.OnDateRangeSelectedListener {

    Switch switch1;
    DateRangePickerFragment.OnDateRangeSelectedListener onDateRangeSelectedListener;
    TextView Name,Phone_num,Skill,Age,Gender,Village;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    String startDate;
    String endDate;

    public LaborerProfile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        makeJsonArryReq();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.laborer_profile, container, false);
        switch1 = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        Name = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Name_L);
        Phone_num = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Phone_L);
        Skill = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Skill_L);
        Age = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Age_L);
        Gender = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Gender_L);
        Village = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Village_L);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Rating_L);


        switch1.setChecked(true);
        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean bChecked) {
                if (bChecked) {
                   showDateRangePicker();
                    // /startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),BusinessActivity.class));
                } else {

                }
            }
        });

        if (switch1.isChecked()) {

        } else {

        }


        return rootView;
    }


    public void showDateRangePicker(){
        DateRangePickerFragment dateRangePickerFragment= DateRangePickerFragment.newInstance(onDateRangeSelectedListener, false);
        dateRangePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
    }

    private void makeJsonArryReq() {
        //     showProgressDialog();

        String URL_PROFILE_L="http://192.168.43.160/webservice/Lprofile.php?phone_num_l="+ Const.USER_ID;

        Log.d("tirth", URL_PROFILE_L);
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_PROFILE_L,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                        try {
                            if (response.length() > 0) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    if (!jsonObject.isNull("user_name_l")) {

                                        Name.setText(jsonObject.getString("user_name_l"));
                                    }
                                    if (!jsonObject.isNull("phone_num_l")) {
                                        Phone_num.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone_num_l"));
                                    }

                                    if (!jsonObject.isNull("age_l")){

                                        Age.setText(jsonObject.getString("age_l"));
                                    }

                                    if (!jsonObject.isNull("gender_l")){

                                        if(jsonObject.getString("gender_l").equals("1")){
                                            Gender.setText("Male");
                                        }else{
                                            Gender.setText("Female");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!jsonObject.isNull("village_l")){
                                        Village.setText(jsonObject.getString("village_l"));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                //  hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateRangeSelected(int startDay, int startMonth, int startYear, int endDay, int endMonth, int endYear) {
        Log.d("range : ","from: "+startDay+"-"+startMonth+"-"+startYear+" to : "+endDay+"-"+endMonth+"-"+endYear );
    }
}
```

and I haven't changed the fragment provided from GitHub

```
public class DateRangePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private OnDateRangeSelectedListener onDateRangeSelectedListener;

    private TabHost tabHost;
    private DatePicker startDatePicker;
    private DatePicker endDatePicker;
    private Button butSetDateRange;
    boolean is24HourMode;

    public DateRangePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static DateRangePickerFragment newInstance(OnDateRangeSelectedListener callback, boolean is24HourMode) {
        DateRangePickerFragment dateRangePickerFragment = new DateRangePickerFragment();
        dateRangePickerFragment.initialize(callback, is24HourMode);
        return dateRangePickerFragment;
    }

    public void initialize(OnDateRangeSelectedListener callback,
                           boolean is24HourMode) {
        onDateRangeSelectedListener = callback;
        this.is24HourMode = is24HourMode;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_range_picker, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        tabHost = (TabHost) root.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        butSetDateRange = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.but_set_time_range);
        startDatePicker = (DatePicker) root.findViewById(R.id.start_date_picker);
        endDatePicker = (DatePicker) root.findViewById(R.id.end_date_picker);
        butSetDateRange.setOnClickListener(this);
        tabHost.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec startDatePage = tabHost.newTabSpec("start");
        startDatePage.setContent(R.id.start_date_group);
        startDatePage.setIndicator("Start Date");

        TabHost.TabSpec endDatePage = tabHost.newTabSpec("end");
        endDatePage.setContent(R.id.end_date_group);
        endDatePage.setIndicator("End Date");

        tabHost.addTab(startDatePage);
        tabHost.addTab(endDatePage);
        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getDialog() == null)
            return;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    public void setOnDateRangeSelectedListener(OnDateRangeSelectedListener callback) {
        this.onDateRangeSelectedListener = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
        onDateRangeSelectedListener.onDateRangeSelected(startDatePicker.getDayOfMonth(),startDatePicker.getMonth(),startDatePicker.getYear(),
                endDatePicker.getDayOfMonth(),endDatePicker.getMonth(),endDatePicker.getYear());
    }

    public interface OnDateRangeSelectedListener {
        void onDateRangeSelected(int startDay, int startMonth, int startYear, int endDay, int endMonth, int endYear);
    }
}
```